# PostgreSQL initdb fails in windows docker container due to no output from postgres.exe

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I am using the base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2-amd64 with the embeddable PostgreSQL found here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries (13.4)

I can't switch to using the postgresql base docker images as I need to run in a windows environment with our systems dependencies installed.

Here's the problem, the postgres executable provides no output when run from inside of the docker container, causing initdb to spit out the following error:

```
no data was returned by command ""C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/pgsql/bin/postgres.exe" -V"
initdb: error: The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the
same directory as "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgsql\bin/initdb.exe".
Check your installation.
```

If you perform the command `postgres.exe -V` in the container, it indeed does not provide any output. However, if you perform the command on the host system using the same binary, you get output: `postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.4`

Is there some kind of system dependency that I am missing, or some kind of system hook that isn't present in docker containers that PostgreSQL relies on?

I have confirmed that my comspec is correct for stdout:

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgsql\bin>echo %COMSPEC%` outputs: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`

Here is the contents of a dockerfile to reproduce the issue:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2-amd64
COPY postgresql-13.4-1-windows-x64-binaries.zip /work/pgsql.zip
RUN powershell Expand-Archive C:\work\pgsql.zip 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL'
```

Here is the containers environment:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=A55C8AEE0AEB
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wb
em;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Loca
l\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgsql
\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
PGDATA=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgsql\data
PGDATABASE=postgres
PGLOCALEDIR=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pgsql\share\locale
PGPORT=5432
PGUSER=postgres
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=8e0c
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=User Manager
USERNAME=ContainerAdministrator
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator
windir=C:\Windows
```

Comment: Pretty much every time I had some problems with the ZIP distribution on Windows, it was because of an outdated VC runtime on the system. You could try to update the VC runtime before running initdb. An alternative to the ZIP archive is to use the installer in "unattended" mode - that can automatically install the VC runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it isn't listed anywhere, there is indeed a dependency on VC++.

Using the x64 installer located here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Headless install: `vc.exe /install /quiet /norestart`

The server is running as expected now in the container.