# Running postgres executable in servercore:1809 does not output anything on terminal

Tags: postgresql, windows, docker, windows-container

I am experimenting to install PostgreSQL in a Windows Container but for some reason when I run `initdb` nothing is printed.
When running `initdb` on my host machine I get an error that I need to either pass `-D` or set the environment variable `PGDATA`.

Steps to reproduce:

```bash
docker run --user ContainerAdministrator --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
curl.exe -L -o pgsql16.zip https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1258697
tar.exe -xf pgsql16.zip -C C:/ --exclude="pgsql/doc" --exclude="pgsql/include" --exclude="pgsql/pgAdmin 4" --exclude="pgsql/StackBuilder"
C:\pgsql\bin\initdb
```

The output is:

```
C:\>C:\pgsql\bin\initdb.exe

C:\>
```

I found something regarding gdi lib but they were are doing something with C#, installing dotnet and such. I do not. So I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Remember that a container is intrinsically a temporary environment; anything you install into that `docker run --rm` container will be lost as soon as you exit the interactive shell.  I'd discourage manually installing software into a running container.  Use a Dockerfile instead, or for things like popular databases, use the standard Docker Hub `postgres` image.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is temporarily to tinker. I I save all commands in a Dockerfile. But there were issues before so I wanted to check if there is something wrong. So far, my issue is: there is not output.

Comment: Also, there are no postgres windows containers that are kind of official and up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000743/12550134

vc++ is missing.

```
curl.exe -L -o vc.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
vc.exe /install /quiet /norestart
```

fixed the issue.